# merge two dfs based on lookup of a common column keeping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pyspark

I have df1 as:

```
import pandas as pd

index = [0, 1, 2, 3]
columns = ['col0', 'col1']
data = [['A', 'D'],
        ['A', 'D'],
        ['C', 'F'],
        ['A', 'D']
       ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
   col0 col1
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F
3   A   D
```

I have df2 as:

```
index = [0, 1]
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data = [['D', 'XX', 'YY'],
        ['E', 'XXX', 'YYY']
       ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
   col1 col2 col3
0   D   XX    YY
1   E   XXX   YYY
```

Length of df1 and df2 is different and df1 has lot of duplicate rows of values where I want to lookup values based on column1 and fetch the results of other columns from df2.

Result df3 should look like:

```
index = [0, 1, 2, 3]
columns = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data = [['A', 'D', 'XX', 'YY'],
        ['B', 'E', 'XXX', 'YYY'],
        ['C', 'F', 'nan', 'nan'],
        ['A', 'D', 'XX', 'YY']
       ]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
  col0  col1  col2  col3
0   A   D     XX    YY
1   B   E     XXX   YYY
2   C   F     nan   nan
3   A   D     XX    YY
```

if the length of df1 and df2 were same then this is working for me:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=["col0", "col1"], right_index=True, how="left")
```

whenever there is a match on col1, no matter how many duplicates are there, I want to populate the rest of the columns for all the duplicates except there is no match and hence Nan.

I can always go for id,row in df.iterrows() but that's not going to scale for my case, i have 1,41,000 rows on df1.

Open to Pyspark solutions as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge, but specify the `left_on` and `right_on`. This will specify the values to compare when merging with `left_on` being the column(s) of the first dataframe and `right_on` being the column(s) of the second dataframe, and `how=left` makes it operate as a left join.

```
import pandas as pd

index = [0, 1, 2, 3]
columns = ['col0', 'col1']
data = [['A', 'D'],
        ['A', 'E'],
        ['C', 'F'],
        ['A', 'D']
       ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)

index = [0, 1]
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data = [['D', 'XX', 'YY'],
        ['E', 'XXX', 'YYY']
       ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="col1", right_on="col1", how="left")
print(df3)

#output
  col0 col1 col2 col3
0    A    D   XX   YY
1    A    E  XXX  YYY
2    C    F  NaN  NaN
3    A    D   XX   YY
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below implementation in Pyspark -

**Input Dataframes**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('A', 'D'),
  ('B', 'E'),
  ('C', 'F'),
  ('A', 'D')
], ['col0', 'col1'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('D', 'XX', 'YY'),
  ('E', 'XXX', 'YYY')
], ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Then, perform a `left join` on `df1` and `df2` using the `col1` column:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on='col1', how='left')
```

This will create a dataframe with columns `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`. 
Next, fill in any null values in `col2` and `col3` with `nan`

```
df3 = df3.fillna({'col2': 'nan', 'col3': 'nan'})
```

Below is the output of `df3` per your requirement -

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col0|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|D   |A   |XX  |YY  |
|E   |B   |XXX |YYY |
|F   |C   |nan |nan |
|D   |A   |XX  |YY  |
+----+----+----+----+
```